# Проблема с JSON строкой!

Tags: json, javascript, php

Такая возникла проблема:

С сервера через ajax получаю данные, в цикле js формирую json для того, чтобы подставить в функцию, строящую графики. Столкнулся с поразительной вещью: если содержимое переменной вывести например через document.write на экран, скопировать и подставить - все работает, а ежели напрямую подставить, то пишет

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined

alert выдает вполне себе корректный код...

JSON такого вида :

```
[{"period":"2014-5-5","Клиенты":"1000","Продажи":"500"},{"period":"2014-5-5","Клиенты":"1000","Продажи":"500"}..... и т.д. ]
```

Формирование в цикле:

```
to_chart +=  "{"+"\"period\":"+"\""+chart_sub[0]+"-"+chart_sub[1]+"-"+chart_sub[2]+"\""+","+"\"Клиенты\":"+"\""+chart_sub[3]+"\""+","+"\"Продажи\":"+"\""+chart_sub[4]+"\""+"}"+",";
```

Подставляем в функцию:

```
var tc = "["+to_chart+"]";


 Morris.Line({
  element: 'staff_chart_container',
  **data: tc,**
  xkey: 'period',
  ykeys: ['Клиенты', 'Продажи'],
  labels: ['Клиенты', 'Продажи'],
  smooth: true,
  lineColors: ["#336699","#009245"],  
 hideHover:true 
});
```

Подскажите решение, друзья)

Comment: Код в студию

Comment: Для просмотра переменных при отладке удобнее юзать console.log(data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RomaRio, вы  понимаете, что переменная `tc` содержит строку с JSON-выражением, а `Morris.Line` в качестве значения параметра `data` ожидает массив JS-объектов.

то есть, грубо говоря, вместо

```
to_chart += "{"+"\"period\":"+"\""+chart_sub[0]+"-"+chart_sub[1]+"-"+chart_sub[2]+"\""+","+"\"Клиенты\":"+"\""+chart_sub[3]+"\""+","+"\"Продажи\":"+"\""+chart_sub[4]+"\""+"}"+",";
```

нужно что-то вроде:

```
// в цикле заполняем
to_chart[i] = {period: chart_sub[0] + "-" + chart_sub[1] + "-" + chart_sub[2], clients: chart_sub[3], sales: chart_sub[4]};
.....
Morris.Line({ element: 'staff_chart_container', data: to_chart, xkey: 'period', ykeys: ['Клиенты', 'Продажи'], labels: ['Клиенты', 'Продажи'], smooth: true, lineColors: ["#336699","#009245"],
```

hideHover:true });

Ну или второй вариант распарсить склеенный вами JSON:

```
var tc = JSON.parse("[" + to_chart + "]");
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, завелось, заурчало, заработало!!!